# using object_getIvar to get var failed (ios)

Tags: ios, variables, runtime

I generate class and assign value to object of the class dynamically, I use method object_setIvar(self, ivar, newValue) to set variable ,but when I use id value = object_getIvar(self, ivar);

it failed, EXC_BREAKPOIT(code =EXC_I386_BPT,subCode=0x0),I saw log in console that [CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fd31eabcbd0, it seems that, when I attempt to set var by object_setIvar, it didn't hold newValue by retain and release it later.

when I use strong ,copy keyword, however,it does not work, still has this error.

anyone encounter the same problem? please give some suggestion, thanks a lot in advance.

```
enter code here
```

void DP_IMPSetter(id self, SEL _cmd,  id newName)
{

```
//remove prefix "set"
NSString * var = [NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3) withString:@""];

//lower first char in string
NSString *head = [var substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
head = [head lowercaseString];
var = [var stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:head];

//remove postfix ":"
var = [var stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([var length]-1, 1) withString:@""];
Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@",var] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


if (!ivar) {
    head = [var substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
    head = [head uppercaseString];
    var = [var stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:head];
    ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@",var] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}

id oldName = object_getIvar(self, ivar);

if (oldName != newName)
{
    object_setIvar(self, ivar, newName);
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

id DP_IMPGetter(id self, SEL _cmd)
{

```
NSString *_var = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
_var = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@",_var];

Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [_var cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

id value;
@try {
    value = object_getIvar(self, ivar);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception = %@",exception.description);
}
@finally {

}

return value;
```

}